# How to create objects named after function parameters and rbind them all?

Tags: r, function, rbind

My goal is to automate some data actualization and analysis from the Brazillian household survey. For doing so, the first step is to create a function that downloads and row-bind several editions of the household surveys.
The good point is that I already have a function that download separate editions of household surveys. It is called 'PNADcIBGE::get_pnadc'. This function gets as arguments "year" and "quarter". So, the long way of doing it:

```
install.package("PNADcIBGE")
library(PNADcIBGE)
pnad_2012_1 <- get_pnadc(year = 2012, quarter = 1)
pnad_2012_2 <- get_pnadc(year = 2012, quarter = 2)
pnad_2012_3 <- get_pnadc(year = 2012, quarter = 3)
pnad_2012_4 <- get_pnadc(year = 2012, quarter = 4)
pnad_2013_1 <- get_pnadc(year = 2012, quarter = 1)
```

And this code would go on... up to `year = 2020 and quarter = 1`.

After loading all the data and naming it accordingly, I would like to row bind all of them:

```
pnad_final <- rbind(pnad_2012_1, pnad_2012_2, ...., pnad_2020_1)
```

I have no idea on how to do it in R, I tried:

```
PCC <- function(a, t) {
 for (i  in 2012:a-1){
  for(j in 1:4){
    Pnadc_i_j <- get_pnadc(year = i , quarter = j)
    }
  }
  for(k in 1:t){
    Pnadc_a_k <- get_pnadc(year = a, quarter = k)
  }
}

PCC(2020, 1)
```

But then I get the error:

```
Error in get_pnadc(year = i, quarter = j) : Year must be greater or equal to 2012.
```

I thought I had set `i` initial value to 2012, but apparently I did not.

I am new to R, but I could do the same in SAS by:

```
%macro PCC(a, t);
%do i=2012 %to %eval(&a.-1);
%do j=1 %to 4;
proc import datafile="H:\IBGE\pnadc_&i._&j..csv"
        out=pnadc_&i._&j.
        dbms=csv
        replace;
%end;
%end;

%do k=1 %to &t.;
proc import datafile="H:\IBGE\pnadc_&a._&k..csv"
        out=pnadc_&a._&k.
        dbms=csv
        replace;
%end;
%mend;
%PCC(2020, 1);

/*And finally, the row-bind is super easy*/

data pnad_final;
set pnadc_20:;
run;
```

Any ideas on how to get something similar in R?

Comment: `pnad_2012_1` is of class `list` with lot of information. Are you looking to extract one of it's element and `rbind` those?

Comment: Hey Ronak Shah, thanks for your comment. According to a tutorial I have (only in Portuguese) pnad_2012_1 should be a `survey.design` object. Yes, with a lot of information. Probably I will further select only some of its columns. But you are right. I expect that they should have about 300k rows and about100 columns.

Comment: I can do select only a couple of its variables to make it smaller: Pnadc_2012_1 <- get_pnadc(year = 2012 , quarter = 1, vars=c("VD4001","VD4002"), savedir = "C:/Users/luizz/R/PnadC")

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with operator precedence. You're missing some parentheses in `for (i  in 2012:a-1)`. It should instead be `for (i  in 2012:(a-1)`). The way you wrote it creates the vector from 2012 to `a`, and then subtracts 1 from every element, since the `:` operator has higher precedence than `-`. This makes the first value of `i` be 2011, giving you that error.

Example:

```
a <- 2020

2012:a-1
# [1] 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019

2012:(a-1)
# [1] 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! You were sure right on this issue! Apparently it is working now! It is still running, and it is expected to take a while, because they are several large datasets. I will wait. While this, do you have any ideas on the second part of the question? On how can I rbind all resulting objects without needing to list them all?

Answer (score 2):

You can create all combinations of data using `expand.grid` and use `lapply` to apply `get_pnadc` function to each combination.

```
library(PNADcIBGE)
data <- expand.grid(year = 2012:2019, quarter = 1:4)

all_data <- lapply(seq(nrow(data)), function(i) 
                   get_pnadc(year = data$year[i], y = data$quarter[i]))
```

`all_data` would be a list of `survey.design` objects. You can extract only relevant parts of it as needed. For example, you can extract only `variable` dataframe from each and combine them into one dataframe.

```
new_data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(all_data, `[[`, 'variables'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing the code and knowledge! I confess I am still figuring out expand.grid and apply. But I got a general idea, and it does seem to be working. But still, I was not able to get the final result. Maybe the datasets are too large for doing everything with a single loop. I got 16GB though, and I could do it in WPS/SAS. It was running for hours, and at some point I get an error message saying the folder to which I was copying and unpacking the files does not exist anymore. Maybe I did something wrong with the loop. I will keep trying to figure it out. Thank you again.

Comment: As soon as I am able to get a result I will post it here. Unfortunately, not yet.